# Equation of a line arises as limit of the equation of two circles in the complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-geometry

Let $u, v \in \mathbb{C}$. Consider the circles centered at $u, v$ such that they intersect exactly at the point $\frac{u+v}{2}$, i.e. $C_u = \partial D_r(u), C_v = \partial D_r(v)$ where $D_r$ denotes the disk of radius $r$ and $r = |\frac{u+v}{2} - u| = |\frac{u+v}{2} - v|$. These circles are given by the equations $|z - u|^2 = r^2$ and $|z - v|^2 = r^2$
which are the same as

$$ z\bar{z} - u\bar{z} - \bar{u}z + u\bar{u} - r^2  = 0, \\z\bar{z} - v\bar{z} - \bar{v}z + v\bar{v} - r^2 = 0.$$

I now want to prove the following fact: The equation of the line $|z - u| = |z - v|$, i.e.
$$-(v - u)\overline{z} + -\overline{(v-u)} z + (|v|^2 - |u|^2) = 0$$
arises as the limit of these equations as $|u|, |v|, |u - v| \rightarrow \infty$.

I truly have no idea how to even begin making sense of this. Geometrically, this seems intuitive enough, a circle of infinite radius *should* be a line. Substituting $r$ into the first equation, we get

$$ z\bar{z} - u\bar{z} - \bar{u}z + u\bar{u} - \frac{(v-u)\bar{v} + (u-v)\bar{u}}{4} = 0,$$

but I don't understand how I can get $v, \bar{v}$ to be a factor in front of some $z$ term (as in the equation I am trying to get) just by taking a limit. What I find particularly troubling is that I get the desired equation simply by subtracting both of the circle equations from each other, but that doesn't feel like I'm doing any sort of limiting process.

Comment: You have to be a little more precise here in what you mean by "limit". In general, a limit should not depend on the limiting variables ($u$ and $v$ in this case), and then you also need a notion of the limit of a sequence of equations.

Comment: @LukasGeyer That is exactly what I am having trouble with. I presented the question as it was posed in a worksheet, and I'm having trouble figuring out what I'm supposed to do here at all. All I know is the fact that I'm somehow supposed to arrive at the equation of the line by increasing the distance between $u$ and $v$ towards infinity.

Comment: I see, then you probably need some clarification from whoever wrote this worksheet... :)